# php sendfile appends filesize to file

Tags: php, download

I have code to serve requested files in PHP. It's testing code, so input is not validated. (By the way, how to correctly sanitize this kind of input...)

```
$upload_dir = "/media/usb/dir";
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$mimetype = $_GET['mime'];
$path = $upload_dir . $filename;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: ".$mimetype );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header("X-Sendfile: \"$path\"");
echo readfile($path);
```

But size of file in bytes is appended to each file. 
For example simple txt like this:

```
myfile
```

Will become this:

```
myfile6
```

How to get rid of this behaviour?

I'm getting textfile like this:

```
download.php?mime=text/plain&filename=my-file.txt
```

Comment: `readilfe()` *outputs* the file and *returns* the number of bytes. Remove the `echo`.

Comment: Apart from that: you should not handle the mimetype specification like that. What sense is there in handing the mimetype over as get argument and then handing it back again? Just leave it away, or detect the mimetype on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

`readfile()` returns the size of the file.  You can add `@` to the beginning of the function to remove the error reporting. `echo @readfile($path);` should display only the filename.

Comment: Everything in this answer is either incorrect, or inadvisable. The error suppression operator should only be used as a *last resort* in the most dire of situations, and `echo @readfile($path);` will *still output the filesize*.